# php how to find SUM of Total payed by class

Tags: php

I have this script which enable user to search Mysql database and it return exactly SUM of total amount payed by a certain class from (2000-2013).

But is not more profitable to me if it return SUM of Total from (2000-2013) as starting year up to ending year.

What I want and difficult to me to query is? to have SUM of Total payed by class to a certain year,

```
example : I prefer user to input year to this format 2012 or 2011 or 2000 or any year   
between(2000-2013)  
in input box and once he click search button it return exactly result of SUM of Total   
of respective year. or any other format that will return desired result.
```

Any help, its real make me unhappy.

Here php script.

```
  <?php

   $date="date";
   $class="class";
   $database=("mcl");
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","mcl");
   @mysql_select_db(mcl) or die( "Unable to select database");


   if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $class=$_POST['class'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];


     $sql="SELECT  *,SUM(school_fee+trans_fee+reg_fee+edutrip_fee+stationery_fee+
      food_fee+uniform_fee+sport_uniform) As Total  FROM payment
     WHERE class like '%".$class."%' AND date like '%".$date."%'"; 

     $q=mysql_query($sql);  

   }
    else{
     $sql="SELECT * FROM payment";
    $q=mysql_query($sql);
        }
    ?>


      <form method="post">
  <table width="500" border="0">
  <tr>
  <td>Class</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="class" value="<?php echo $class;?>" /></td>

  <td>Date</td>
  <td><input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo $date;?>" /></td>

  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  </form>
  <table>
  <h4>
      Total amount of money payed by&nbsp;<?php echo $class;?> &nbsp<?php echo  
       $date;?>class&nbsp;</h4><hr> 
     <table width="1100" border="0" height="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" >
     <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF9900" width="400">Class</td>
     <td bgcolor="#FF9900" width="200">Total</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FF9900" width="200">Date</td>
</tr>
<?php
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
?>

<tr>
    <td width="100"><?php echo $res['class'];?></td>
     <td width="200"><?php echo $res['Total'];?></td>
    <td width="280" style="border-width:medium"><?php echo $res['date'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php }?>    



 </table>
```

Here the Table

```
$num="create table payment
(id int primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
fk_id varchar (10) NULL,
idnumber varchar (10) NULL,
fname varchar (50) NOT NULL,
class varchar (15) NOT NULL,
school_fee FLOAT(8,2),
trans_fee FLOAT(8,2),
stationery_fee FLOAT(8,2),
reg_fee FLOAT(8,2),
food_fee FLOAT(8,2),
uniform_fee FLOAT(8,2),
edutrip_fee FLOAT(8,2),
edutrip_name varchar (20),
fee_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
uniform_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
register_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
food_setting FLOAT(8,2),
edutrip_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
stationery_setting FLOAT(8,2),
trans_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
sport_uniform FLOAT(8,2),
sport_setting FLOAT(8,2) NOT NULL,
date date NULL)";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *,SUM(school_fee+trans_fee+reg_fee+edutrip_fee+stationery_fee+
      food_fee+uniform_fee+sport_uniform) As Total  FROM payment
   WHERE class like '%".$class."%' AND YEAR(date) = '$date' GROUP BY YEAR(date)
```

Assuming `$date` is 4 digit number.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't SUM up all records  of certain year, it just take only one between two or more record and return the answer

Comment: Sport on Mihai, I get the result.